# How does the brain know what to crave?

Tags: decision-making

I remember that at some point on House, M.D., one of the characters mentioned that her patient craved milk because it contained some chemical he/she needed. How does the brain figure out what chemicals it can get from what foods, and by extension what to crave? I know one craves very specific foods, but I eat a lot of foods per meal so I don't see how the body can connect something to its composition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out this question on biology.stackexchange: [Do omnivore mammals vary food preferences based on dietary needs?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5090/do-omnivore-mammals-vary-food-preferences-based-on-dietary-needs)

The answers in that question mention that experiments on Rats and Birds determined that there's an internal **chemosensor, the anterior piriform cortex (APC)** within bird and rat brains that senses lack of Indispensible Amino Acids (IAA). Animals show aversion to foods that lack IAA in as short as 20-30 minutes.

There's another example listed that mentions that being sodium deficient makes animals like salt more. Their preference for salty taste increases.

I don't know if these findings apply to humans though.

Comment: Hm... that seems like it would explain it. Do you have any ideas on foods eaten together, or multiple courses in the same meal? Maybe just a process of elimination after eating the same thing several times?